# C++/CLI : How do I declare abstract (in C#) class and method in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, abstract-class, declaration, abstract-methods

What is the equivalent of the following C# code in C++/CLI?

```
public abstract class SomeClass
{
    public abstract String SomeMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just mix up the keywords a bit to arrive at the correct syntax.  *abstract* goes in the front in C# but at the end in C++/CLI.  Same as the *override* keyword, also recognized today by C++11 compliant compilers which expect it at the *end* of the function declaration.  Like `= 0` does in traditional C++ to mark a function abstract:

```
public ref class SomeClass abstract {
public:
  virtual String^ SomeMethod() abstract;
};
```

Comment: Is there any difference between declaring "SomeMethod() = 0" and "SomeMethod() abstract"?

Comment: No.  = 0 is C++ syntax but C++/CLI supports it too.

Answer (score 7):

You use `abstract`:

```
public ref class SomeClass abstract
{
    public:
        virtual System::String^ SomeMethod() = 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between declaring "SomeMethod() = 0" and "SomeMethod() abstract"?

Comment: Nope.  The Method() = 0 is the non-C++/CLI (just stnadard C++) way of defining an abstract class.  With C++/CLI, you can use it, or the new abstract keyword.  I prefer using the original, since it's just habit, and the abstract keyword is context sensitive in the case of a method, but either works.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0z6b513(VS.80).aspx